# Does the order in which I turn off the gas stove matter?

Tags: stove, gas

I have a gas stove. This is connected to a big gas canister (I don't know the volume, but I'd guesstimate 20-30 liters). Whenever I want to cook, I turn on the valve on the gas canister, as well as the knob for the corresponding stove plate.

When I'm finished, I ususally turn off the stove knob first, followed by the valve on the canister. Would it be safer, waste less gas, or have any other effect to turn off the gas canister first, followed by the stove?

**Edit**: the stove has no safety features - you're free to turn on both the gas valve and the stove knob and let the gas flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this type of stovetop for many years. The way I usually did was:

- Turn off the stovetop
- turn off the canister

The next time you turn the canister on, gas won't leak through the burner you left on (because you didn't!). And the amount of gas left in the connecting hose is negligible and should be safe to leave it there until the next use.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to turn of the stove first. This leaves gas in the line so it lights easy. Turn on the gas before the stove to light. This saves that 30 seconds it takes for gas to refill the line. We use 20lb bottles here. Our stoves ovens here are more like you would have had in the 50s in America. No safety on them. 3rd world & all. May not apply to your Country.

Answer (score 0):

Here, were I am at (Germany) gas stoves have a safety that allows gas to flow only while you hold the knob or while flame is burning. This is monitored by a temperature sensor on the side of the burner. On a stove like that it would not matter what you turn off first.

But as a common TV trope is for some murderer to turn of the gas stove and leave I guess that's not the case in the US. But even then turning the stove off should stop the gas flow. I don't have experience with this kind of stove but I'd guess that there, too the order would not matter.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, there are no safety features like that on this stove. I've updated my question to include this information.

Comment: Are you sure the gas is flowing out of the canister when the stove is off? We have a gas range hookup here with a butane (or propane) tank hooked up by hose, musch the same as you describe. No gas flows until the hob is lit. If your stove has an electric ignition (e.g. you're not using a match), then I'd suspect this is the case as well.

Comment: Hi Umbranus, I am not sure how this relates to the question. If you mean to imply that a certain order is necessary (which one) or not necessary when you have a stove with this security feature, I cannot follow it straight from your post, please add it.

Comment: @rumtscho I edited my answer and hope it's now clearer.